# Java modify database while running jar

Tags: java, database, jar

I'm implementing a stand alone application which need to be delivered as a jar file.
To handle with a number of large input data which is bigger than 1G per each, I figured out that integrating the application with db(e.g. H2) is a alternative way to handle large data.
However I have to deliver the sw as a jar file which is read-only. So I'm curious that if there is any efficient way to make tool's own database on user pc and do sql queries like INSERT, DELETE, etc.
The input data will be loaded by user and I wanna put all data inside the db(not in memory) to handle with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) could be what you need, but I don't know if it can support big data sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a database like [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) with [memory only](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch01.html#N101CA) tables. That way you could load the data to work with at application start into the database and than modify it in memory without having to write back to disk.

You should be aware that this will require a high memory footprint for your application, maybe temporary files would be an alternative?

Comment: I found that it also support embedded database. This is what I was finding. Thanks.